# Microsoft Translator fails returning 400 continually

Tags: c#, api, translation

I implemented the MS Translator API a C# console app. 
My subscription level is a premium pay account, NOT the free level.
Each time I begin calling it, the first 1-5 translations work fine.
After that I get and endless stream of 400 (Bad Request) exceptions.

Here is the text response I'm getting:

> Response Text: TranslateApiException Method: Translate() Message:
>   Cannot find an active Azure Market Place Translator Subscription
>   associated with the request credentials.message
>   id=3832.V2_Rest.Translate.117038D9

What am I missing? I am most definitely including the app id and secret key in the code?

Am I intended to also provide some additional credentials?

Here is my Translator class:
Any ideas?

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Translator
{
    private string AccessToken;
    private DateTime TokenExpirationDate;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Translator()
    {
        AccessToken = "";
        TokenExpirationDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    public void GetAccessToken()
    {
        if (AccessToken != "" && DateTime.Now < TokenExpirationDate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Translator: usng existing token");
            return;
        }

        AccessToken = "";
        string clientID = "<-removed->";
        string clientSecret = "<-also-removed->";
        String strTranslatorAccessURI = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
        String strRequestDetails =
              string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1} &scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientID),
              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strTranslatorAccessURI);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequestDetails);
        webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (System.IO.Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse webResponse = null;
        try
        {
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AccessToken = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        if (webResponse != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
            AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            AccessToken = token.access_token;
            TokenExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(token.expires_in));

            if (AccessToken.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine("Translator: got an access token.");
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    public string Translate(string textToTranslate, string destLanguageCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Translator(" + destLanguageCode + "):" + textToTranslate);

        string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textToTranslate) + "&from=en&to=" + destLanguageCode;
        System.Net.WebRequest translationWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
        translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        System.Net.WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Translator: Fail: " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        if (response != null)
        {
            System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

            System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Translator(" + destLanguageCode + "):" + xTranslation.InnerText);
            return xTranslation.InnerText;
        }

        return "";
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class AdmAccessToken
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Without looking at the code - the fact that the first few requests are working *suggests* that you *might* be getting rate-limited. how often are you doing these requests? are you complying with the T&Cs the API has laid out?

Comment: A 400 - Bad Request could also mean your request is malformed. Have you tried watching the request in Fiddler to see if there is a problem?

Comment: It works for 4 or 5 requests. Then nonstop 400's.

Comment: Then it must be rate limiting. Don't do several requests per second.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the content of the response. It will contain the cause of the error in human-readable form.
It is likely that you do not have a subscription associated with the credentials of your request. To fix that:

- Visit https://datamarket.azure.com/account/datasets and make sure you have a subscription to "Microsoft Translator - Text Translation".
- Visit https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications and define a client ID and password.
- Use that client ID and password in your application.

Comment: My initial post made it fairly clear that I am paying for an account and have the client id and secret key in the app already.

Comment: Make sure you have a subscription to "Microsoft Translator - Text Translation".